# Could 50 or 200 kHz light up a neon line tester?

Tags: frequency

I want to confirm there is output from an echo depth sounder that's transmitting at 50 or 200 kHz, 1-3 kW.

Could the output of an echo depth sounder light up a neon line tester in contact?

Comment: Possibly. How many volts?

Comment: How far away is it? What is the incident electric field intensity?

Comment: Is pulse with 5Vp-p

Comment: Is transmitting in a form pulses with 5Vp-p